# Troubleshooting VS C#/SQL Server Compact setup - "event log file full" message

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to develop a little C# application (with MS Visual Express and SQL Server) and am having an issue trying to figure out the error dialog that pops up:  "the event log file is full"

I'm following these instructions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983322.aspx

In MS Visual C#, I have the "Database Explorer" window open.  There is an item that says "Data Connections".  When I right click on that item, and click "Add Connection..." that's when I get the error message.

My system is Windows XP SP2.

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.  I'm not new to SQL (I'm a MySQL person), but I am still new to the MS SQL Server stuff.

-Adeena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty the event log and try again:

- Windows-R ("Run") - eventvwr
- For each event log (in the left hand pane) right-click and select "Clear all events" (backing up the existing log if you care)

Comment: Got it - but my properties on the individual log files are set to "overwrite events older than 7 days" - and there's a ton of events listed that are much older than 7... hmm... it worked, but I didn't realize the MS error message was related to my system.  Thanks!