# SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not work in VS 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce-4

I've installed SQL Server compact 4.0 local database and I've added a database. However, if I try to open my database, an unknown errors occurs.

I tried to restart my VS 2010 after install the SQL Server, but it does not help and I cannot open my database.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not pay attention on a error message: "event log file full".
I just cleaned eventviewer in Windows and all became okay:).

I spied this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407402/troubleshooting-vs-c-sql-server-compact-setup-event-log-file-full-message):

I just emptied the event log and tried again:

- Windows-R ("Run")
- eventvwr

For each event log (in the left hand pane) right-click and select "Clear all events" (backing up the existing log if you care)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following [blog](http://erikej.blogspot.in/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html)

In this blog you will see that you need to download an additional tool to make it work with visual studio 2010. The link to this tool is present in the same blog (search for the text below) or you may download it using the Web Platform Installer.

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0