# Locating DataSource for DataGridView

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running Visual Studio Express 2008 (Windows App, targeting framework 3.5) along with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I have a form and a DataGridView (dgv1). I'm tring to add an SQLS file to VS as the data source for dgv1 using the Designer. My .mdf (named 'Staging') is located at
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Staging.mdf

In the Properties window for dgv1, the DataSource property is currently set to (none). I click the dropdown and then "Add Project Data Source". I choose 'Database' and arrive at the "Choose Your Data Connection" screen with the question, "Which data connection should your application use to connect to the database?". The dropdown for answering the question is empty and when I click on the "New Connection" button, the dialog box closes without showing further options -- dead end. I'm wondering if my SQLS file is in the wrong place and VS can't see it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps.

1. Using the *[Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=7593)* add the database *Staging.mdf* file to your SQL Server.  This is done by: Under **'Object Explorer'** window, right clicking the **'Databases'** folder then select **'Attach...'** then click the **'Add...'** button and select your *Staging.mdf* file.
2. Go to Visual Studio and under **Solution Explorer** right click your project then **Add** then **New Item...** and select a **DataSet** under Data.
3. Now your project will have a new *DataSet1.xsd* file.  (The name *DataSet1.xsd* is the name you gave it under the previous step).  Double click it and you will see on option in the middle saying *"Drag database items from Server Explorer or the DataSet Toolbox onto the design surface, or right click here to add new items"*.  Use the **Server Explorer** to add the tables from your **Staging.mdf** file.  This is done by dragging the table found under **Data Connections** then open up the **Tables** folder under your *computer name*, drag this table into the *DataSet1.xsd* window.

Once you do that you can go to your C# code and add a line like this:

```
DataSet1TableAdapters.YourTableNameTableAdapter tableTA = new DataSet1TableAdapters.YourTableNameTableAdapter();
```

Now you can use the *tableTA* object to access your data.  Also you can add your own Queries by double clicking the *DataSet1.xsd* file in the **Solution Explorer** then right click the *tableAdapter* and select **Add Query...**.  You will see the new query on your *tableTA* object (after you build your app).

Also on your **DataGrid** you can select the **DataSource** by going to your **Form** then click the **DataGridView1** you will see a little triangle on the top right corner, click it, then select the table you added on the *DataSet1.xsd* under the **Choose Data Source** drop down box.

Please ask me if you get lost on a step.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your recommendations. Here's what I've done: Since I had created Staging.mdf using SQL Server Management Studio, it's already in place. In VS, I opened the Database Explorer but there's nothing under 'Data Connections'. This so weird and makes me think that VS may be looking in the wrong place but I can't tell where exactly it's looking.

Comment: Hi Tim, so you don't have anything under *Data Connections* if you go on the top menu of Visual Studio then click View -> Server Explorer -> Data Connections?  Maybe there is a login issue to the SQL Server if you don't see anything.  You should see your server name and database name and under there the Tables it has.

Comment: Correct. On my VS2008Exp version, it's called Database Explorer. Nothing below 'Data Connections' even when I right-click>Refresh. If I right-click>Add Connection, I get an error that "The event log file is full". My SQL database is in place and responds fine within SQLS when I run queries against it. Can you elaborate on the possible log-in issue?

Comment: This helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407402/troubleshooting-vs-c-sql-server-compact-setup-event-log-file-full-message

Comment: Yes, I don't have VS 2008 installed anymore.  My references were more for VS 2010 or VS 2013.  I guess we need to figure out this connectivity issue between VS and the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a clogged log file (or two) was blocking access to seeing objects in the Database Viewer (and anywhere else where you can create a data connection). The url posted here and above contains the answer. To summarize, clear the logs by opening the command window and using the 'eventvwr' command and clearing all the logs listed in the viewer. You can then add the data connection and see the db.

Comment: Glad you found the issue.